Oracle 19c ORA-02291 parent key not found
First time, long time. Love this place for finding answers to my dumb questions! Scarily, I'm Oracle self-taught (because it was thrown on my plate at work) and I have this occasional problem I simply can't figure out. Here's the summary:
-We have a system that actuates inhalers
-A camera captures high-speed images
-The images are put into the database with a corresponding information
-The user can then go back into the program to view the images, filtering by the corresponding information
Sometimes, this ORA-02291 error occurs. I can see that something can't be referenced, but I have no idea what. Successful pieces of data I'm assuming are exactly the same. I'm trying to narrow down whether the corresponding data can't be inserted to a table, or the images themselves can't be inserted.
By looking at this, anyone have an idea? Or at least a more in-depth explanation for what ORA-02291 actually means?! Thanks!!!
Event Date/Time   Event Type  Event Class Event Code  System Type System Serial # Event Note
10/07/2024 03:04:18 PM  Error   Database Exception  -2147217900 123 456 * Test Engine.vi

Manage Images.vi

Txfr Compressed Images to Database.vi

Rollback Transaction on Error.vi
Saving Shot Images

Execute SQL Command (no data returned).vi:2
 insert into actuation_images
 (actuation_id, seq_nbr, image, image_type)

  (select 14549011115595030000007290, 
    NULL, blob_data, 
     'zip' from blob_temp where blob_id = 14549011115595030000008647)




Exception occured in OraOLEDB:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SV.FK_ACT_IMAGE) violated - parent key not found

SQL Developer to cross-reference corresponding data and images.

You have a table, which may have been created from a DDL statement that looks something like:
CREATE TABLE actuation_images (
  actuation_id NUMBER,
  seq_nbr      NUMBER,
  image        BLOB,
  image_type   VARCHAR2(10),
  CONSTRAINT FK_ACT_IMAGE FOREIGN KEY (actuation_id)
                          REFERENCES actuations (id)
);

There are four columns and then a constraint which is a foreign key and that means that the values in the actuation_images.actuation_id column must also appear in the referenced column in, using this made-up example, the id column of the actuations table.
When you try to insert the row:
insert into actuation_images (actuation_id, seq_nbr, image, image_type)
select 14549011115595030000007290,
       NULL,
       blob_data,
       'zip'
from   blob_temp
where  blob_id = 14549011115595030000008647

Then while trying to insert the data into a new row of the actuation_images table the database will check the constraints and if there is a row in the referenced actuations table that has the id value of 14549011115595030000007290. If it does exist then the row can be inserted but if it does not exist then the database will raise the exception:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SV.FK_ACT_IMAGE) violated - parent key not found

What you need to do is make sure that the row with that primary key is inserted into the referenced table (actuations in this example but your actual table may differ) exists before you try to insert a row that references it into the actuation_images table.
fiddle

Thank you SO MUCH!!!! I'll go back and look at the build scripts to see what's what. That actuation_id table is used for a ton of stuff so I had a feeling it was involved. :-D
